# Add dependency and plugin in seperate file using "apply from" in gradle

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

My `build.gradle` inside app directory contains:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral();
        jcenter()
    }
}
def hasBuildExtras = file('build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras) {
    apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
}
```

And this is my `build-extras.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:1.2.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.triplet.play'
```

Am I correct to assume that `build-extras.gradle` should be "merged" inside original file? No matter how I move it around I get `Error:Plugin with id 'com.github.triplet.play' not found.`
If i move `classpath 'com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:1.2.2'` up to the main file and leave just `apply plugin: 'com.github.triplet.play'` inside `build-extras.gradle` then it seems to work fine. So am I wrongly defining dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

A build.gradle file can only ever have one `buildscript` block. You are correct with the paragraph explanation. Add the plugin dependency to your main build file's `dependencies` block within the `buildscript`, then conditionally apply the plugin using whatever logic you'd like.

Comment: My problem is that the original `buildscript` is generated, so I can't really modify it. It is supposed to be `extended` with this file. I guess I have to look for other solutions. Thank You!